# Checking for touch keyboard in windows 8 tablet/pc

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8

I need to find out if I am a tablet, I think checking for a keyboard is the best, as I know I am on windows 8, and all i want to do is show the soft keyboard if I am a tablet.

So i thought about checking the keyboard capabilities as many seem to suggest, but KeyboardCapabilities don't exist in .net 2 according to VS2012.

```
// Determine if a keyboard is present and change the input mode accordingly
Windows.Devices.Input.KeyboardCapabilities kc = 
     new Windows.Devices.Input.KeyboardCapabilities();
if (kc.KeyboardPresent == 0)
    //show the keyboard here
```

I have found websites which show how to add windowsRT access via 
`<targetplatformVersion>8.0</Targetplatformversion>`
and then importing windowsruntime.dll from .net4.5  core, which allows access to the KeyboardCapabilities, but not in the same project as winforms.

But my app needs to run under windows 8,7,XP etc, and its running on .net 2.0 using winforms

So How do I access these dll's in .net 2? or how do i add wrap them for use in 1 class or separate dll?

Comment: why do you keep posting so many answers, just post comments. its like you keep talking to yourself in here.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you call tabtip.exe
it will show the touch keyboard if not already present, and if its running in services it means its available on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

the answer so far is there is no way to do this, 
you cannot access both winforms and windows.devices in the same project.